# Motorola Defy Gallery app is crashing upon start

Tags: 2.1-eclair, gallery, motorola-defy, crashes

I have for a couple weeks a Motorola Defy with Android 2.1 (Eclair), since today the **Gallery app crashes upon start**, the screen is shown for a less than a second and then it dies.
The only odd thing I did was adding a ".nomedia" file to directories where I store music so that the disc covers would not show up on the Gallery app.
How can I fix that? Can I reset just that app?

Thanks

Comment: Already cleared the app data.

Comment: I gave up, I reset the phone and it started working again. It seems that another app, don't know which caused this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Settings > Applications > Manage applications > Gallery > Clear data`?

Comment: The app is not visible on that app list. With a third party app manager (Super Manager) I was able to clear the Gallery's data. Only to see it taking couple minutes to load and fail the same way.